# How to stop the foreach loop while adding more buttons then I close the form suddenly without error: Cannot access a disposed object?

Tags: winforms

I am creating a room management form with the flow panel layout added 410 buttons, I use *Thread* to view the added buttons one after the other. The problem is that when I click the X button in the upper right corner, the program reports at *MethodInvoker* an error:

**"ObjectDisposedException was unhandled"**

**An handled exception of type 'System.ObjectDisposedException' occured in System.Windows.Forms.dll**

**Additional information:Cannot access a disposed object.**

How do I stop the foreach loop when I close the form? Currently I only hide that form when closing so that it doesn't get an error.

My code:

```
public fPhong()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            load();
        }

        void load()
        {
            Thread thr = new Thread(loadPhongList);
            thr.IsBackground = true;
            thr.Start();
        }

        void loadPhongList()
        {
            List<phong> phongList = phongDAO.Instance.phong();

            foreach (phong item in phongList)
            {
                    Button bt = new Button() { Width = phongDAO.phongWidth, Height = phongDAO.phongHeight };
                    if (item.SONGUOIDANGO == 0)
                    {
                        bt.Text = item.MAPHONG + Environment.NewLine + "Trống";
                        bt.BackColor = Color.AliceBlue;
                    }
                    else
                        if (item.SONGUOIDANGO > 0 && item.SONGUOIDANGO < item.SLTD)
                    {
                        bt.Text = item.MAPHONG + Environment.NewLine + "Có người";
                        bt.BackColor = Color.Aquamarine;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        bt.Text = item.MAPHONG + Environment.NewLine + "Đầy";
                        bt.BackColor = Color.Red;
                    }
                    bt.Click += Bt_Click;
                    bt.Tag = item;

                    Thread.Sleep(5);
                    if (flpPhong.InvokeRequired)
                    {
                        flpPhong.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(delegate () { flpPhong.Controls.Add(bt); }));
                    }
            }
        }
void Bt_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        string maphong = ((sender as Button).Tag as phong).MAPHONG;
        loadTT(maphong);
}
```

Comment: Don't create those Buttons in a Thread, which, btw, exists just to add a delay of 5ms. If you need a delay, create your Buttons, add them to a `List<Button>`, then add them to their Parent in an `async` method where you `await Task.Delay(5)` in a loop and you'll be ok.

Comment: can you guide me add List<Button> in flow layout panel bro? I'm newbie :((